# lower bond of $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Is this inequality true for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

$$
 |\cos(x)-\cos(y)|\ge 1- \cos(x-y).
$$

Comment: Consider something like $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: What is the relationship between $~\cos(a) - \cos(b)~$ and $$-2 \times \sin\left( ~\frac{a-b}{2} ~\right) \times \sin\left( ~\frac{a+b}{2} ~\right) ~?$$  If the two expressions are equivalent, does this help you attack your problem? ...see next comment

Comment: Re last comment, knowing that $$\cos(r+s) = \cos(r)\cos(s) - \sin(r)\sin(s),$$ what happens if you set $$r = \frac{a+b}{2}, ~s = \frac{a - b}{2} ~?~$$  Then, how would you evaluate the two expressions $~(r + s),~$ and $~(r - s)~?$

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=(x+y)/2$ and $D=(x-y)/2$, so $x=M+D$ and $y=M-D$. From the angle-sum formulas we have $\cos x -\cos y=-2\sin M \sin D,$ and also $1-\cos (x-y)=2\sin^2(((x-y)/2)=2\sin^2 D.$

So the inequality is $$| -2\sin M \sin D|\ge 2\sin^2 D.$$

But $M,D$ can be any members of $\Bbb R.$ So take any $D$ such that $0\ne \sin D,$ and then take any $M$ such that $|\sin M|<|\sin D|,$ and the inequality will be false.